# How to make a table of consecutive integers in Amazon Redshift SQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to create a table in Amazon Redshift SQL or in PostgreSQL that will contain consecutive integers from 0 to some large random number. This should be done without using arrays which are not supported in Redshift version of SQL.

Comment: postgres or redshift?, please choose the one you need as the answers are very different

Comment: Removed the Postgres tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_numbers_1000 AS 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() 
FROM stl_scan 
LIMIT 1000;

SELECT * FROM tmp_numbers_1000 ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10;
 row_number
------------
          1
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
          8
          9
         10
(10 rows)

SELECT * FROM tmp_numbers_1000 ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 10;
 row_number
------------
       1000
        999
        998
        997
        996
        995
        994
        993
        992
        991
(10 rows)
```